# Turning a string back into an array with #join method

Tags: ruby, join

I am trying to reverse each word of a string.

```
def reverse(string)
  words=string.split(" ")
  words.each do |word|
    new_string = word.reverse!.join(" ")
  end
end

reverse('hello from the other side')
```

Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

Comment: In what sense is it not working?

Answer (score 2):

`.join(" ")` is in the wrong place. Move it to the end of your penultimate line:

```
def reverse(string)
  words=string.split(" ")
  words.each do |word|
    word.reverse!
  end.join(" ")
end

reverse('hello from the other side')
  #=> "olleh morf eht rehto edis"
```

I removed `new_string =` because it does nothing.

As you gain experience with Ruby you will find you could write this more compactly as follows:

```
def reverse(string)
  string.split.map(&:reverse).join(" ")
end
```

Comment: I would go with `string.gsub(/\S+/, &:reverse)`.